# Creating gitlab oauth token via authentication

Tags: oauth, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

According to [the docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html#resource-owner-password-credentials), `POST`ing to `/oauth/token` with

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "user@example.com",
  "password"      : "sekret"
}
```

should respond with something like

```
{
  "access_token": "1f0af717251950dbd4d73154fdf0a474a5c5119adad999683f5b450c460726aa",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 7200
}
```

However, my gitlab server seems determined to reply to this request with `404`:

```
$ http POST $GITLAB_API_HOST/api/v3/oauth/token grant_type=password username=$GITLAB_USERNAME password=$GITLAB_PASSWORD
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 03:24:16 GMT
Server: nginx
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Request-Id: a6dc1303-f1e8-43a2-8c47-227d5de533c7
X-Runtime: 0.003662

{
    "error": "Not Found", 
    "status": "404"
}
```

I wasn't able to find an working example of this flow. Is there something I need to do to enable this endpoint on my gitlab (ee) installation?

Comment: Confirmed that this doesn't work on https://gitlab.com either

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the endpoint for these tokens is *not* under `api/VERSION`.

```
http POST $GITLAB_API_HOST/oauth/token grant_type=password username=$GITLAB_USERNAME password=$GITLAB_PASSWORD                                   2.3.0 master ●●
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 03:33:11 GMT
Etag: W/"6431af790cc9c53891e0cb58b64d845c"
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 6fafc1a6-eaef-4c39-aa81-6d8fcf40a196
X-Runtime: 0.150464
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
    "access_token": "5b4a8a98d009bb569f4302d98f2aafe5362b7a06c1b12367a9658172b993c6c8", 
    "created_at": 1463369591, 
    "refresh_token": "57cfe9a90eabe0ed70336d7aad91f16bfa437e50d6d6f0b88de0e20c2e02167f", 
    "scope": "api", 
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

*not actual tokens

Comment: It's been a while, but I think so